# Getting (null) when I Parse the number from webservice

Tags: ios, web-services

I have to display the price of the product from webservice but the value is (null)

```
 NSArray *arr = [pJson objectForKey:@"Response"];
    NSLog(@"%@",arr);
    for (int i=0;i<arr.count;i++) {
        NSString *thumbnail_data = [[arr objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"img"];
        NSString *ring_data = [[arr objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"name"];
        NSString *id_data = [[arr objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"ID"];
         NSString *cost_data = [[arr objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"productprice"];
        NSLog(@"THUMBNAIL: %@",thumbnail_data);
        NSLog(@"AUTHOR: %@",ring_data);
         NSLog(@"AUTHOR: %@",cost_data);
        dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                      thumbnail_data, img,
                      ring_data,name,id_data,ID,cost_data,cost,
                      nil];
        [myObject addObject:dictionary];
    }

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    subCatCell =(ProductCollectionViewCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ProductCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSDictionary *tmpDict = [myObject objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSMutableString *detail;
    detail = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
              [tmpDict objectForKey:name]];
   // NSNumber *price = [tmpDict objectForKey:cost];
    NSMutableString *price;
    price = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
          [tmpDict objectForKey:cost]];
    NSLog(@"%@",price);

   // NSMutableString *catid;
    catid = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
             [tmpDict objectForKey:ID]];

    NSMutableString *images;
    images = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ",
              [tmpDict objectForKey:img]];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[tmpDict objectForKey:img]];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    img= [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:data];

    subCatCell.imageView.image = img;
    subCatCell.lblCost.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",price];
    subCatCell.lblName.text = detail;
    return subCatCell;
}
```

When I NSLog the "cost_data" price is displayed correctly but when I NsLog "price" in cellForItemIndexPath I'm getting "(null)"

Comment: can you please print the content of `myObject` array ?

Comment: u were allocated the memory of `myObject`

Comment: My cost_data is not added to myObject array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you are not allocated memory for `NSDictionary` or `NSMutableArray`. kindly do the following changes it may solved your issue.

**Step 1** : Allocate `myObject` in `viewDidLoad`

```
myObject = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

**Step 2** : Replace set of below codes.

```
NSArray *arr = [pJson objectForKey:@"Response"];
    NSLog(@"%@",arr);
    for (int i=0;i<arr.count;i++) {
        NSString *thumbnail_data = [[arr objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"img"];
        NSString *ring_data = [[arr objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"name"];
        NSString *id_data = [[arr objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"ID"];
         NSString *cost_data = [[arr objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"productprice"];
        NSLog(@"THUMBNAIL: %@",thumbnail_data);
        NSLog(@"AUTHOR: %@",ring_data);
         NSLog(@"AUTHOR: %@",cost_data);
      NSDictionary*  dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                      thumbnail_data, @"img",
                      ring_data,@"name",id_data,@"ID",cost_data,@"cost",
                      nil];
        [myObject addObject:dictionary];
    }
```

Comment: Still I'm getting only first two objects added to my dictionary

Comment: means your dictionary have only two keys. img, name. right?

Comment: yeah if I replace img with cost then price is getting displayed

Comment: Change the creation of NSDictionary like as belowed
NSDictionary*  dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                 thumbnail_data, @"img",
                                 ring_data,@"name",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",id_data],@"ID",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",cost_data],@"cost",
                                 nil];

Comment: Now cost is added to myObject but ID is (null) and NSMutableString *price is also (null)

Comment: have you replace NSDictionary creating code ? that is in my last comment.

Comment: yeah after replacing only cost is added to myObject but in cellForIndexPath when I NSlog "price" its displaying (null)

Comment: can you print myObject array after it created ? so i will get idea.

Comment: can you please add following code in your `cellForItemAtIndexPath`.

 NSDictionary *tmpDict = [myObject objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"Price : %@",[tmpDict objectForKey:@"cost"]);